# Magento 2 cookies not saved correctly and deleted sometimes

Tags: magento2, addtocart, cookie

I have strange behavior in Magento 2.2.4 and also 2.2.5. If I add a product to the cart it is saved correctly and mini cart shows 1 product. Then I add another product and the first added product is lost in the cart, only the second added product is in cart.

**If I disable full page cache everything is fine.**

Comment: I found out, that if pages are in cache - everthing is ok ...!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem - it seems that some modules must be enabled. I had enabled following and now it is working. I do not know which one and also do not know why:
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_Multishipping
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_Braintree
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_Persistent
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_Authorizenet
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_QuoteAnalytics
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_SendFriend
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_Captcha
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_Ups
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_Usps
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_Weee
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_WishlistAnalytics